# Can I Enable simplexml on php.ini?

Tags: joomla, simplexml, php

I've been using Joomla 1.6 locally on my computer.  Everything's been working fine.  I uploaded the web files to the company's server and all of a sudden I'm getting the following error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function simplexml_load_file() in...

I've checked several online communities and some people are saying that simplexml should be enabled.  I checked phpinfo.php and simplexml seems to be enabled on my computer; while it is disabled on the company server.

I don't have the privileges to enable this on the company server, so I was wondering if it will be possible for me to use php.ini to enable simplexml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ext/simplexml` cannot be enabled in a `php.ini`. It either is enabled in your PHP installation (that's the default) or it has been disabled intentionally. You should contact your responsible administrator... In my opinion it's not really the best idea to disable core extensions such as `ext/simplexml`, `ext/dom` and so on - a lot of code builds upon those extensions, and XML capabilities should be considered a core feature.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I have asked the server admin to enable it; but he takes forever to get something done so that's why I asked if I would be able to enable it through php.ini.  I guess I'm just looking for an alternative method rather than having to wait for this guy to act.